# web site already exist issue?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template. And I am using command,

```
stsadm -o restore -url http://machinename:8090/siteabc -filename c:\backup\siteabc.bak
```

But met with the following error -- there is a web site already exist on "/siteabc". Please specify a new URL or using -overwrite.

How to check whether there is a web site called "/siteabc" already exists? Not sure whether tools like SharePoint Manager could detect this?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... How about opening a browser to http://machinename:8090/siteabc? You could also look in the Site Collection List under Application Management in Central Administration.

Comment: 1. From "Site Collection List", how to know if a site called siteabc exists? Appreciate if you could share more details about how to check. I am a newbie for this topic. 2. Is it possible that this site is created by other applications (not SharePoint)? If yes, how to check?

Comment: Question answered!